# GPG Not Working

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, 18.04, gnupg

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1.
I previously had GPG 2.1.15 (including dependencies) manually installed from gnupg.org.
I wanted to install a ppa and after running `sudo apt-key add Release.key` I got the output:

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
```

I then went on a wild goose chase to fix that. The wild goose chase ended poorly. I uninstalled GPG2 (and dependencies) using `sudo make uninstall` in the directory for GPG2 and each dependencies. I then installed GPG2 and its dependencies via apt.
I am now completely unable to use GPG.

When I run `gpg --clearsign` I get the output

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running
gpg: no default secret key: No agent running
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No agent running
```

When I run `gpg-agent --daemon` I get

```
gpg-agent: relocation error: gpg-agent: symbol gcry_get_config version GCRYPT_1.6
           not defined in file libgcrypt.so.20 with link time reference
```

When I run `gpg --version` I get

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.7.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/michael/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
    CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: why not just install from repos? `sudo apt install gnupg2`

Comment: I did that. I uninstalled the manual installation and installed GPG2 through apt.

Comment: try `sudo apt purge gnupg2 && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt install -y gnupg2` ... this should give you a for sure clean install

Comment: Will this delete my secret key or other keys that I have on my system?

Comment: as long as they are in your home folder, you are OK. backup to be safe... maybe rename your .gnupg folder to something else first... then you can see if it works with fresh config and move your keys back over

Comment: It's still broken

Comment: try `sudo apt install --reinstall libgcrypt* gpg-agent` as the manual install seems to have broken this library...

Comment: GPG is still broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually uninstalled, reinstalled and then again uninstalled libgcrypt 1.7.0 by going to the directory with the files I downloaded from [gnupg.org](http://gnupg.org) and running

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
sudo make uninstall
```

I then reinstalled libgcrypt through apt by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgcrypt20*
```

I then went to the directory for libgpg-error 1.21 and did the same for libgpg-error 1.21.

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
sudo make uninstall
sudo apt install --reinstall libgpg-error0
```

I then went to the directory for libassuan 2.4.2. I manually installed and then uninstalled libassuan 2.4.2 before reinstalling libassuan through apt.

```
sudo make install
sudo make uninstall
sudo apt install --reinstall libassuan0
```